# Sitecore language version font family

Tags: css, cookies, sitecore

I have a Sitecore page with multiple languages. Is there a way to have different font-families for different languages? The language information is set in cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the cookie it is simpler to set the language in the HTML and use that in you CSS.

Example in Sitecore set in your Layout something like:

```
<html lang="@Sitecore.Context.Language.CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName">
```

In CSS you can no use something like:

```
p:lang(en) {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
p:lang(ja) {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```